# sortBy is late with one click in background

Tags: jsf, primefaces, columnsorting

I have this problem when I'm trying to perform a sorting by a column using sortBy attribute in Primefaces. Using the sort event I realized that the order of the rows is updated in UI, but in the backend the list is not changing and it changes only after I perform another sorting, but it changes with the order of the old column selected, so the order in backend is with one sorting behind. I can perform correctly other operations on the table and I can save the values in the database. The only problem is with the ajax sort event or with the attribute sortBy.

```
  <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="row"
rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
rowsPerPageTemplate="10,50,100,200,300" paginatorPosition="top"  paginator="true" rows="10"
value="#{table.rows}" rowKey="#{row.id}"
selection="#{data.selectedRow}" selectionMode="single"
styleClass="table">
<p:ajax event="sort"
  listener="#{manager.testUpdate}"
  update="dataTable" />
<p:column
  headerText="id"
  styleClass="align"
  sortBy="#{row.id}">
  <h:outputText value="#{row.id}" />
</p:column>
<p:column
  headerText="name"
  styleClass="align"
  sortBy="#{row.name}">
  <h:outputText value="#{row.name}" />
</p:column>
```

.....

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @umaair_653 yes

Comment: Works great in the PrimeFaces Showcase for normal and lazy datatables. Find the difference and create a [mcve]